# NGRX Entity test in component

Tags: ngrx

I have a component with an entity selector 'selectAllProperties' in ngOnInit, and I want to test this component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadPropertiesRequested());
    this.properties$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllProperties));
    this.loading$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectPropertiesLoading));
    this.logs$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectPropertiesLogs));
  }
```

In my spec file, i initialized the store like in the ngrx doc:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({
          ...fromRoot.reducers,
          feature: combineReducers(fromProperties.reducer),
        })
      ],
      declarations: [
        SidebarPropertiesComponent,
        SidebarElementComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

- When I launch the tests, I have 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined'.
  All the others selectors do not produce errors
- I also would like to mock the Observable returned by each selector.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem, in TestBed.configureTestingModule

instead of

```
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      ...fromRoot.reducers,
      feature: combineReducers(fromProperties.reducer),
    })
  ],
```

use

```
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    StoreModule.forFeature('properties', fromProperties.reducer),
  ],
```

- No more 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined'
- I can mock the properties

> ```
>  it('should have 2 properties elements', () => {
>    store.dispatch(new LoadPropertiesSuccess({properties: propertiesMock}));
>    fixture.detectChanges();
>
>    const list = debugElement.queryAll(By.css('li'));
>    expect(list.length).toBe(2);
>  });
> ```